# Canon LiDE 110 - Device busy

Tags: usb, scanner, canon

I have a Canon LiDE 110 scanner that has worked for me on previous Ubuntu version (18.04) but is not working anymore on Ubuntu 20.04.

When I access the scanner with scanimage I get "Device busy"

I have followed several google links to check permissions and used lsusb and sane-find-scanner to detect the scanner.

`lsusb` lists my scanner:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04a9:1909 Canon, Inc. CanoScan LiDE 110
```

I then tried `sane-find-scanner`, it does find it

```
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9 [Canon], product=0x1909 [CanoScan]) at libusb:003:002
```

but then `scanimage -L` does not list it anymore

```
> scanimage -L

No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
```

So I followed some links to check permissions,

```
> ls -l /dev/bus/usb/003/002
crw-rw-r--+ 1 root saned 189, 257 Sep 18 09:45 /dev/bus/usb/003/002
```

Checked and added myself to the `saned` group

```
> groups
florian adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin scanner saned sambashare kvm
```

I also tried to access that device with cat (does work, prints some non-print characters)

But this command (to test) fails with permission / device busy

```
> scanimage -d genesys:libusb:003:002 --format tiff --mode gray -l 0 -t 0 -x 210 -y 297 --resolution 300 -p
scanimage: open of device genesys:libusb:003:002 failed: Device busy
```

fuser does not show any usage of the device though:

```
> fuser -a /dev/bus/usb/003/002 
/dev/bus/usb/003/002:
```

So, what else can be wrong that I cannot access my scanner?
Note that it has worked before the system upgrade (using 18.04). Unfortunately that is a while back and I haven't scanned since then

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue and wanted to note that `fuser` needs to be run as root in order to work properly.  I got blank output like you did at first, but running the command as root revealed the desired PID.